# How to push new data from Realtime Database to Cloud Firestore?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, zapier

I am pushing data to Firebase via Zapier and it lands in the Realtime Database. However, I am using Cloud Firestore. I've looked through a lot of documentation for both services but neither seems to have answers.. (there is information on migrating but I would like to keep both DBs).

How would I push each new or updated data entry from Realtime Database to Cloud Firestore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing built into Firebase to automatically do this.

The fastest I can think of is to build a Cloud Function that listens for the Realtime Database writes, and then also sends them to Firestore.

Alternatively, doesn't Zapier allow you to have two zaps, one that writes to each database?

Comment: They do, I missed it the first time around. Currently checking with them to ensure the zap not only creates the record in Cloud Firestore but updates as well.